# Dynamic width cell of grid in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, grid, swiftui-gridrow

Hi everyone I'm having problems with a Grid and its contents. As you can see from the image, each cell expands as much as the text contained in it. It spreads too much...
I would like the description (long text) to be spread across multiple lines if it exceeds a hypothetical width limit.

---

[image]

---

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong in my code or what kind of changes I need to make?

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        Grid {
                            ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
                                GridRow {
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                            Text("Lorem".uppercased())
                                                .bold()
                                                .font(.footnote)
                                            Text("Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem ")
                                                .font(.caption)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                .padding(16)
                                .background(.secondary.opacity(0.1))
                                .clipShape(.buttonBorder)
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Since you are using scrollView with horizontal alignment, it is natural that text extends itself in a single line. If you want to wrap them in multiple line try setting "width/maxWidth" for that long Text using "frame"

Comment: It's because the ```Grid``` is wrapped in a ```ScrollView``` with horizontal scrolling. If you comment out the ```ScrollView``` then the text wraps automatically. From your example, it's not clear why you are using a ```Grid``` at all, because each ```GridRow``` only contains one view, so the grid only has one column. This means, you could just have used a ```VStack``` instead. Perhaps you need to update your example to show more data (in particular, more columns) if your layout issue is more complex than what you have illustrated so far.